# in python, how to match Strings based on Regular Expression and get the non-matching parts as a list?

Tags: python, regex

For example: I have a string "abcde2011-09-30.log", I want to check if this string matchs "(\d){4}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}" ( dont think it has correct syntax, but you get the idea). And I need to split the string into 3 parts: (abcde),(e2011-09-30), (.log). How can I do it in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) method in the `re` module that should work for you.

```
>>> s = 'abcde2011-09-30.log'
>>> re.split('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', s)
('abcde', '2011-09-30', '.log')
```

If you don't actually want the date as part of the returned list, just omit the parentheses around the regular expression so that it doesn't have a capturing group:

```
>>> re.split('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', s)
('abcde', '.log')
```

Be advised that if the pattern matches more than once, i.e. if there is more than one date in the filename, then this will split on both of them. For example,

```
>>> s2 = 'abcde2011-09-30fghij2012-09-31.log'
>>> re.split('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', s2)
('abcde', '2011-09-30', 'fghij', '2012-09-31', '.log')
```

If this is a problem, you can use the `maxsplit` argument to `split` to only split it once, on the *first* occurrence of the date:

```
>>> re.split('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', s, 1)
('abcde', '2011-09-30', 'fghij2012-09-31.log')
```

Comment: That worked great, David. Also thanks everyone for your prompt answers.-- a new python guy coming from java background :)

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "abcde2011-09-30.log"
>>> myregexp = re.compile(r'^(.*)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(\.\w+)$')
>>> m = myregexp.match(a)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7f69480>
>>> m.groups()
('abcde', '2011-09-30', '.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

*(without using regex and interpreting your string as a filename:)*

lets start with splitting the filename and the extension 'log':

```
filename, ext = os.path.splitext('abcde2011-09-30.log')
```

most probably, the length of the date is allways 10, allowing for:

```
year, month, day = [int(i) for i in filename[-10:].split('-')]
description = filename[:-10]
```

However, if you are not sure we can find out where the date-part of the filename starts:

```
for i in range(len(filename)):
    if filename[i].isdigit():
        break

description, date = filename[:i], filename[i:]
year, month, day = [int[c] for c in date.split('-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact python regex syntax but something like this should do the job:

```
/^(\D+?)([\d-]+)(\.log)$/
```